# C Dynamic linking and security of signed tokens

Tags: c++, c, security, linker, token

I have a question regarding the security and integrity of my application when it comes to dynamic linking. I'd like to ship an application to my client together with libcrypto.so that does some signature verification of some JWT tokens. Now ideally I'd like my client not to "hack" my security (I don't want to allow him to feed his own tokens).

Let's assume my dynamic library has a method as such:

myLib.so

```cpp
void verifyToken( std::string token ) {
 if( externalLibVerifyToken( token ) ) {
   // verified
 } else {
   // not verified
 }
}
```

An external library (for example libcrypto.so):

```cpp
bool externalLibVerifyToken( std::string token ) { /* verify it and return */ }
```

Now, my application ships with myLib.so and libcrypto.so and uses dynamic C linking (std::string is just for example purposes).

What happens if someone, for example the target audience, replaces libcrypto.so by another one, exposing the same symbols, but bypassing all kind of verification ? They could technically screw up with my verification strategy, correct ?

And second question: can I somehow mitigate that ?
Surely I could use libcrypto.a and embed it in mylib.so, but perhaps there is a better strategy ?

Comment: Depending on the determination of a cracker, you can not really protect against that, as long as the client has all information on his system. You can make it harder, but not impossible.

Comment: `std::string` doesn't look like C.

Comment: When you running code in an untrusted system (like a client's computer) you must assume that an attacker has full access to your code. Moving verification code from an external library into a static library only increases the time it takes to find and weaponize the exploit. An experienced reverse engineer will find the verification code and patch your executable in less than an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a software developer, you rely on the security of the computer and operating system on which the software will run.

If the user with admin right want to hack your software, you mostly can't do anything about it. Just think that it's not only about replacing the dynamic library, but he (the user) could even modify the software and fully remove the `if` statement.

If the user is your enemy, just run the software on a server under your security & control.

Comment: For this to happen, we would have to go through the machine code and make his modifications there. That's a lot more effort than switching a dynamic library for another... No ? Running on a server would be a no-go. It's for an Android app that *needs* to run on the phone itself (i.e. offline).

Comment: Replacing a library with an equivalent is not much easier. Obviously, is not something you do my mistake, it require a clear intention, knowledge and time. You can protect yourself with the license, but that (legal protection) is not sufficient in case you are managing security-critical content (health privacy, ideological privacy, money/goods).

Comment: If what you need is just to make the hack harder, there are some code obfuscation mechanims making the hack much harder (but not fully reliable). As you speak of cryptographic security, I assumed that to be insufficient.

Comment: But there's no access to the code... only machine code (or did I miss something ?). That's definitely hard enough to read and I don't think anyone would bother doing that (not worth it), so I don't need to further obfuscate it. But replacing libcrypto by an empty shell sounds like it would be super easy (never tried though). The header files are all public. It'd be enough to recompile from source after emptying all functions from their substance.

Comment: Modifying binary is not that hard: Any decent IDE is able to roll back binary to assembler, which then is easy to spot the call and remove the jump instruction (think about all those software with license check hacked and published online).

Comment: Ok well at least I can't say I haven't tried.